# Trying to delete all records in a list based on a where clause

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

All of my workflows for a site have the ability to log data in the Workflow History list on my site.  This is controlled at run-time with a parameter in list based on the workflow Name.  I would like to be able to run a workflow on this setup table that will delete all records in the History list.  My understanding is I can do this via REST call in SharePoint Designer workflow.

I have attempted many times to configure the REST Post command in Designer and I am never able to get this to work.  I've searched over and over for a solution and not able to find such a solution.

I first tried deleting all that had the Workflow Association ID equal to the Workflow Name, but could not get that to work.  Then I thought I would try selection each value using REST and then deleting that value using REST by the ID I received from the GET.

This is my delete (POST).

```
[%Workflow Context:Current Site URL%]/_api/lists/GetByTitle('Workflow History')/GetItemObject('[%Variable: HistoryID%]')
```

I also tried the DeleteListItem

```
[%Workflow Context:Current Site URL%]/_api/lists/GetByTitle('Workflow History')/DeleteListItem('[%Variable: HistoryID%]')
```

I want the user to be able to run this on any workflow from the setupWorkflow list I have.  The workflow should delete all history for the current workflow.

Answer (score 0):

We can get the list items in Workflow History list base on the WorkflowInstance, in designer workflow, we can get the **Instance ID** from the **Workflow Context**.

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Workflow%20History')/items?$filter=WorkflowInstance eq 'b87b131e-ce22-43f5-85be-ec81d1045bc7'
```

Then delete list item using REST API below.

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Workflow%20History')/GetItemById(ID)
```

The following articles for your reference.

[Using HTTP Call/ Rest API from SharePoint Designer workflow to create list](https://praveensharepointknowledgebase.wordpress.com/2018/06/25/using-http-call-rest-api-from-sharepoint-designer-workflow-to-create-list/)

[workflow to delete list item on subsite( Sharepoint designer call http web service )](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/181522/workflow-to-delete-list-item-on-subsite-sharepoint-designer-call-http-web-servi)

Comment: I've coded it, it runs, but nothing deletes.  The response from the call is ok.  My one REST call has my requestHeaders defined with Accept, Content-Type (defined as usual REST calls) and X-HTTP-Method String DELETE, and IF-MATCH String *    My actual REST call is an HTTP POST using the following URL [%Workflow Context:Current Site URL%]_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Workflow History')/GetItemById(ID).  The HTTP Service Properties:  RequestHeaders: request Headers (my dict I definded above), RequestContent: requestHeaders, ResponseContent: response Content and ResponseHeaders: responseHeaders

Comment: Not certain what's going on.  But know i'm getting bad request and I'm a bit perplexed.  I just tried different lists and now back to the original.

Comment: This thread never really solved my problem and so I asked my question differently and did get an answer.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63251214/my-history-table-is-too-large-to-view-over-5k-records-trying-to-create-workfl