# My history table is too large to view (over 5k records). Trying to create workflow to delete entries

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I have a workflow that queries the history table returns a list of IDs and trying to delete each of those items.
My first REST call is

```
<site URL>/_api/lists/GetByTitle('Workflow%20History')/Items?$select=Id
```

This returns a valid set of records, then I have a second rest call to delete a record It's a POST REST call with the end point:

```
<site URL>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Workflow History')/GetItemById(1)
```

I get a bad request as a response to the second REST call.  I'd prefer to not select and then delete and just delete based on a filter condition.  Any assistance, I would appreciate some help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refer to this post to delete list item using rest api in workflow: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ef8057c3-c96a-4d04-b3c4-4c8bcd7ce2d2/sharepoint-designer-2013-call-http-web-service-delete-workflow-not-working?forum=sharepointdevelopment

the header dictionary should as below:

[image]